# LFS Chapter 3.1 zsh: command not found: wget

Tags: arch-linux, wget, lfs

Hi I am making LFS on Black Arch VM. I am currently at Chapter 3.1 I ran command `wget https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/11.0/wget-list` But I got error `zsh: command not found: wget`. I run before I started build my LFS `sudo pacman -S wget` to get wget but I got:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) wget-1.21.2-1

Total Download Size:   0.72 MiB
Total Installed Size:  3.08 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages...
 wget-1.21.2-1-x86_64                                 739.1 KiB   193 KiB/s 00:04 [##############################################] 100%
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                    [##############################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                  [##############################################] 100%
error: wget: signature from "Levente Polyak (anthraxx) <levente@leventepolyak.net>" is unknown trust
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/wget-1.21.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.`
```

Do you have ideas how can I resolve this errors? Thank you for your answers and advices.

I tried `pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring && pacman -Syyu` but I got

```
error: failed retrieving file 'wget-1.21.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.rackspace.com : Failure writing output to destination warning: failed to retrieve some files error: failed to commit transaction (download library error)
```

Comment: It'd be useful (to others) to [edit] your post with the commands you ran and their output. Did you try to reinstall wget after the pacman command?

Comment: Again, these should be in an [edit] to your question. It looks like you're back to the problem in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687894/i-am-trying-to-install-wget-command-black-arch-linux-vm-but-i-got-error! Do you have enough free disk space where it's downloading to?

Comment: @JeffSchaller maybe there should be problem bcse when I created second partition Linux I let it take the rest of the disk at last sector